# sorting NSArray of strings with numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array that contains these string.

```
@"Common Area",
@"Building 1",
@"Building 2",
@"Building 3",
@"Building 4",
@"Building 10",
@"Building 14",
@"Car Park",
```

I am then trying to sort alphabetically like this

```
areaArray = [areaArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

but its displayed like

```
@"Building 1",
@"Building 10",
@"Building 14",
@"Building 2",
@"Building 3",
@"Building 4",
@"Car Park",
@"Common Area",
```

Where as I would like it to be displayed as

```
@"Building 1",
@"Building 2",
@"Building 3",
@"Building 4",
@"Building 10",
@"Building 14",
@"Car Park",
@"Common Area",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code sample will do the magic.

```
NSArray *stringsArray = @[@"Common Area", @"Building 1", @"Building 2", @"Building 3", @"Building 4", @"Building 10", @"Building 14", @"Car Park"];


static NSStringCompareOptions comparisonOptions = NSCaseInsensitiveSearch |
NSNumericSearch |
NSWidthInsensitiveSearch | NSForcedOrderingSearch;

NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

NSComparator finderSortBlock = ^(id string1, id string2) {
    NSRange string1Range = NSMakeRange(0, [string1 length]);
    return [string1 compare:string2 options:comparisonOptions range:string1Range
                     locale:currentLocale];
};

NSArray *finderSortArray = [stringsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:finderSortBlock];

NSLog(@"finderSortArray: %@", finderSortArray);
```

Comment: Better yet, use sortUsingSelector and sort using localizedStandardCompare. Much simpler than the above, with the same results.